# Ошибка в интернет-эквайринге Тиннькофф

Tags: php, банковские-карты, интернет-эквайринг

Тестирую платежи на демо-терминале.
Тип подключения - Универсальное
Уведомление - по протоколу HTTP
Путь к скрипту прописан верно, содержимое скрипта

```
<?
$tinkoff_confirm = $_POST;
print_r ($tinkoff_confirm);
$confirm_text_string = implode(';',$tinkoff_confirm);
$fp = fopen('tinkoff.txt','w');
fwrite($fp,$confirm_text_string);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

то есть я просто хочу записать данные совершенного платежа в файл на сервере.

Но на стороне Тинькова выскакивает ошибка
*

> Ошибка нотификации: не получаем ответ "OK" на следующие запросы
> нотификации: CONFIRMED Проверьте и поправьте обработку нотификаций:
> CONFIRMED. После этого повторите тест-кейс.

- 

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Данная ошибка практически всегда говорит о том, что не корректно указаны url нотификации (нотификации, страница успешного платежа и страница ошибки оплаты)

Comment: Я об этом читал уже, но url указан верно. Когда я с любой другой формы ставлю action= этот url, то скрипт срабатывает. Просто интересно, влияет ли на ошибку содержимое скрипта?

Comment: Во-первых, добавьте ссылку в вопрос, во-вторых, попробуйте выключить нотификации и провести тест

Comment: С выключенными нотификациями тесты все проходят, с нотификацией по е-майл тоже проходит тест.

Comment: Включите и ещё раз попробуйте

Comment: Та же ошибка после включении нотификации по HTTP. URL правильный 100% формата `https://sitename/pay/confirm/`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128845/discussion-between-denis-i-and-indevx).